# Adding a local WCF Service for DB

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to retrieve some data but the service I'm trying to reach is behind a closed ip connection so i can't test my code from personal pc. I was told to add the database that service that I can't reach relays to.

I have added the Database, however now i also need to add the service so i can start testing this is where I get stuck all I was given was the following code for the service:

The database is included in the solution and it's working named: PUBS.MDF I now need to add the following service so i can reference it and then test my code.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPubs
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Publication> GetTopTitles();

    [OperationContract]
    List<Publication> GetTitles(string SearchString);

    [OperationContract]
    PublicationDetail GetPublicationDetails(string PubID);
}

[DataContract]
public class Publication
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PubID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class PublicationDetail
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PubID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> Authors { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime PubDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So, what's your question? What have you tried?

Comment: I dont know how to create a WCF Service with that ServiceContract that i was provided. I created a WCF Service Application and added the microsofts PUBS database to App_Data folder.  

Then i opened IService1.cs and deleted it's [ServiceContract] and [DataContract] and pasted in the one i got. Now i understand i need to keep my WCF service runing so i can access it via reference string on my other Visual Studio instance where i will make my page to display the data.

Comment: However i dont understand how to create the relation between the Service and the Pubs database.

Comment: Were you supplied with an implementation of Pubs or have you just got IPubs?

Comment: I have been supplied whit a copy of Pubs database which i did add to my App_Data folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the code for IPubs and the database, you *could* write a Pubs class that implements IPubs, but you would be guessing how it works so it would not be a proper test.

I suggest you go back to the people that supplied the interface and database and ask for a copy of the service classes they have that implement IPubs. If they can't supply that you could ask them to define what inputs should produce what outputs, then create a mock service that you can test your client against.